# Why does this callback return undefined?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
function firstFunction(num, callback) {
  callback(num);
};

function secondFunction(num) {
  return num + 99;
};

console.log(firstFunction(56, secondFunction));
```

> > ```
> > undefined
> > ```

If I call `console.log` from within `secondFunction`, it returns the value.

Why not? What's the point of setting up callbacks if I can't get the value out of them to use later? I'm missing something.

Comment: You forgot the chain the return value from `callback`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your function `firstFunction`, you do:

```
callback(num);
```

Which evaluates to

```
56 + 99;
```

Which is then

```
155;
```

But you never return the value! Without a return value, a function will simply evaluate to `undefined`.

---

Try doing this:

```
function firstFunction(num, callback) {
  return callback(num);
};
```

Comment: You've answered the question. Juts on a quick sidenote though, say that the secondFunction had a setTimeout(), and contained the return in it and delayed it somehow. It seems if that's the case, the original one doesn't wait on it and just returns undefined again.

Comment: What would be the option if thats the case?

Answer (score 2):

`firstFunction` does not return anything, plain and simple! That is why when you `console.log` the return value, it is `undefined`.

The code in question:

```
callback(num);
```

calls `callback` and then does nothing with the returned value. You want:

```
return callback(num);
```